# Can I use Java 8's JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) with Java 7 and Java 6?

Tags: java-8, backwards-compatibility, jce

I need to use the `SecretKeyFactory` `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512` which is availble in Java 8's JCE.
Is it possible to add those files to Java 7 and JAva 6 installations as well?

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Thanks, but I copied the two jar files into Java 7's security folder and it didn't do anything. No providers were added under `Security.getProviders`

Comment: If you refer to lib\security\\*.jar: These are just the policy files. Under lib\ext you find some files like sunjce_provider.jar, but I do not believe that's feasible. The providers (J8/J7) would have the same name, so you would have to replace the other...

Comment: I just did and it kinda f*** me up ....